# Using Powershell to grep for the word pattern "Exception" in files

Tags: unix, powershell, grep

Background :

I have a log server with tons of gzip files containing text logs information.

Among these logs, there are "Exception" tags being written onto the text files and I would like to use powershell to find all the available "Exception" tags entries in the log text files.

I have been trying using the Powershell with the following cmdlets option but I am stuck at the point to get the content inside the text files of the gzip files before I use `Select-String` to "Grep" out the word pattern "Exception" in the text files.

```
Get-ChildItem '##Location of my log files directory###' | 
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1 |
    Get-ChildItem | ###Lists of my gzip log files###
```

Question:

Could anyone advice me on how to enumerate through all the gzip log files in order to get the "Exception" tags entries written in all of the log files. Please do give examples in the form of Powershell Scripts or Powershell cmdlets.

Sincerely,

Derek

Comment: You want to look in **all** the files? Because right now you are only looking in the most recent one.

Comment: Well I do want to look in all files but the point is how to read through zip files ?

Comment: Do you have a command line compression utility like 7-zip installed?

Comment: check out this for unziping http://serverfault.com/questions/18872/how-to-zip-unzip-files-in-powershell

Comment: I don't get why you have this tagged with unix. Powershell is a Windows 'feature'. Good luck.